# Redundant condition in PHP code or not?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, logical-operators, isset

Many PHP developers write the following conditional statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'someValue') {
  something();
}
```

What is it useful for to write this conditional statement?

When I look at it, it seems that if `$_POST['action'] == 'someValue'`
implies that `isset($_POST['action'] == TRUE`.

So, it seems that the following conditional statement will do the same:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'someValue') {
      something();
}
```

Comment: if $_POST['action'] is not set it will write a warning in error log..checking isset will avoid producing that warning

Comment: you will get a undeclared variable warning with the second approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just call:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'someValue') {
   something();
}
```

and `$_POST["action"]` is not set, then the default PHP behaviour is to complain about `undefined index`, which will result in a `direct string output`.
Now consider if your PHP request was all about sending a JSON back to the client... Your JSON would be a `malformed one`.

Another issue, consider the following:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'someValue') {
   something();
}
...
header("Location: foo.php");
```

Sorry, no chance since your notice about `undefined index` preceed the header and this is a no-no. It will not work since the default behaviour of PHP (considering error reporting is ON) is to spit warnings in string format, thus messing the flow of your script.

Of course, you could silencing these errors with this:

```
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'someValue') {
   something();
}
```

but this is an equally bad practice, it doesnt make the program better but slower and harder to catch errors.

Answer (score 1):

PHP emits a notice if an undefined variable or index is used.

That check is there to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

If a key in an array doesn't exist, PHP will trigger a notice on accessing it. So it's not redundant, but it depends on your settings if the notice is shown.